# How to convert $x^3+y^3-x^2+y-1=0$ to homogenous form using the variables $X,Y,Z$

Tags: algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I'm to figure out how to convert algebraic curve such as $x^3+y^3-x^2+y-1=0$ to homogenous form using the variables $X,Y,Z$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: so far I've used tried to clear out the denominator.

Comment: Hint: make the change of variables $x\mapsto X/Z$ and $y \mapsto Y/Z$, then clear denominators.

Comment: $x^3+y^3-x^2+y-1=z^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with $x = X$, $y = Y$, i.e. simply renaming the variables, then trivially

$$
X^3+Y^3−X^2+Y−1 = 0
$$

Now you multiply each term by either $Z^3, Z^2, Z^1$ or $Z^0 = 1$ so that the sum of the exponents of each term is $3$. So $X^3$ and $Y^3$ gets multiplied by $1$, $X^2$ gets multiplied by $Z$ and so on. You end up with

$$
X^3+Y^3−ZX^2+Z^2Y−Z^3 = 0
$$